# template management with wordpress (underscore boilerplate)

Tags: wordpress, templates, wordpress-theming

I am using [underscore](https://underscores.me/) to develop a wordpress theme.

I have a custom post type name `project`, thus I have, for instance, this url: `http://a.site.local/projects/a-beauty/`.

I have in my `template-parts/` directory the file `content-projects`.

```
$ cat template-parts/content-projects.php 
<h1>Project</h1>
```

When I browse `http://a.site.local/projects/a-beauty/`, I have my title **but also the sidebar and the footer** (even if they do not appear in my `content-project.php` nor in `index.php`).

Where are those widgets coming from / loaded ?

Comment: I'd assume templates have `<?php get_header(); ?>` ,  <?php get_footer(); ?> , `<?php get_sidebar(); ?>` Check the templates for them ( header.php, footer.php and maybe sidebar.php ). I don't recommend removing the functions in your pages, just add conditional statement in that template (header or footer) for certain pages or archive types. 
Refer to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_footer/.

Comment: Exactly ! `underscore` has those snippets in template `single.php` https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/post-template-files/#single-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add conditions to the header, footer and sidebar.

For whole custom post archive:

```
<?php if( !is_post_type_archive( 'project' ) ) : ?>
    // wrap the code you don't want to show on that archive
<?php endif; ?>
```

For custom post only:

```
<?php if( !is_singular( 'project' ) ) : ?>
    // wrap the code you don't want to show on the post
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you want to put the code you WANT to show, remove the '!' before condition.

P.S.
You can put the whole  content in a condition, but keep the

```
</div><!-- #page -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

otherwise the page will break :)